# Essential KRunner plugins I should need for text searching

Tags: krunner

I like KRunner (been using similar for Mac called Spotlight) but it has an overload of plugins and does not always find what I need which is mostly text searches.

Basically what I would like is to be able to find all files that contain text (E.g. txt, pdf, docx, csv, conf, .hidden text files etc as well as matching filenames / application names.)

I would like to know which plugins are essential for text and filename searching.  I've enabled only **Applications, Desktop Search, Locations, Places, Plasma Desktop Shell**. Seems to work much better.

I've also setup my indexing of **/home/user** and **/etc** directories.

Am I missing anything though?